# Ng-repeat datas from 2 json Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I try to get data from 2 jsons and list it in table :

1st 'names.json':

```
[
        {
            "name": "AAAAAA",
            "down": "False"

        },

        {
            "name": "BBBBBB",
            "down": "45%"
        },
        {
            "name": "CCCCC",
            "down": "12%"
        }
]
```

Second 'data.json'

```
[
         {
            "data": "25-12-2014"
        }
]
```

Javascript:

```
 app.service('service', function($http, $q){
            this.getNames = function () {
    var datas =  $http.get('data,json', { cache: false});
    var names =  $http.get('names.json', { cache: false});
    return $q.all([datas, names]);
};
});

    app.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, service) {
     var promise = service.getNames();
     promise.then(function (data) {
     $scope.names = data.names.data;
     $scope.datas = data.datas.data;
});
```

Now i must show it in table HTML :

```
div ng-controller="FirstCtrl"
     <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="name in names.concat(datas)">
            <td>{{name.name}}</td>
            <td>{{name.data}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

I try concat() but it dont work, is there any method to show in table datas from 2 arrays by ng-repeat?
Thanks for answers in advance!

Comment: can you console  `$scope.datas` and `$scope.names` in controller and paste the result here?

Comment: in console i have 2 arrays, no errors @Sravan

Comment: what does it show in html?

Comment: @Sreehari it dont see array datas

Comment: There is no problem with array concat inside ng-repeat. It is working fine

Comment: let me know is this your expected output 
AAAAAA 25-12-2014
BBBBBB 25-12-2014
CCCCC 25-12-2014

Comment: I had a similar problem, and it was subsequently resolved. See question at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44392404/two-different-json-sources-update-at-different-times-use-result-in-ng-repeat-l/44399420#44399420