# Refresh/ TImer function for only 1 of 2 feeds -- $q.all() merge

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout, q

This is a question based off my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44392404/two-different-json-sources-update-at-different-times-use-result-in-ng-repeat-l).

Essentially, I've used the $q.all() method to resolve multiple http calls. Then I filter and merge the two data sources.

This all works really well. But I want one of my two feeds to refresh every 5 minutes. Normally, I would do this by appending the following timer to the end of my code

```
var timer = $scope.intervalFunction = function() {
    $timeout(function() {
       /* function to call $http.get again */
        $scope.intervalFunction(); 
    }, 300000)
}; 
timer(); 
$timeout.cancel(timer);
```

My issue is, since I don't define the http calls as separate functions, and I also "merge" both sources, how do I call one of these sources only, and then update accordingly without making multiple list item copies (which is something that has happened to me in many attempts).

Thank you!

JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/KateJean/n2L2fzst/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I want one of my two feeds to refresh every 5 minutes". I'm not sure that you can do the trick with one of two `$q.all` requests. I just can advice you to make another request outside of your `$q.all` wrapper and start `$timeout` for it after your getting the result of first `$q.all` request.

Need to say, that I'm not absolutely sure in this solution because I didn't test it, but hope this will works:

```
$q.all(promises)
  .then(function(response) { 
    metadata = response.metadataPromise.data;
    metrics = response.metricsPromise.data; 
    joinMetadataAndMetrics();
    requestEveryFiveMinutes(); 
  })
  .catch (error) (function (error) { 
    console.log(error);
  });

function requestEveryFiveMinutes() {
  $interval(function() {
    // here you can make the needed http request
    yourRequest()
      .then(function() {
        // handle the response as needed
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      })
  }, 300000);
}
```

And don't forget to inject `$interval` in your controller

Comment: I think you're right. I'm looking for some good examples but I'm coming up short. 

so if I have:
   $q.all(promises).then(function(response) {
      metadata = response.metadataPromise.data;
      metrics = response.metricsPromise.data;
    
      joinMetadataAndMetrics();
    }).catch (error) (function (error) {
        console.log(error); 
    }); 

How would I make that second request and activate a $timeout?

Comment: @KateJean, I said `$timeout`, but mean `$interval`. And I have updated the answer, check it out.

Comment: you're definitely right. Indeed -- I am able to get the call to work ever 5 minute  interval like I wanted. 

However, instead of the list entries simply updating with the new information, the list entries appear again with the previous entries. So if I have 10 entries the first call, I'll suddenly have 20 the second call.

I put the joinMetadataAndMetrics() function in my .then portion of the requestEveryFiveMinutes() (because I figured the data merge would need to be done again). Obviously this is causing the repetition, but I'm not sure how to resolve it.

Comment: @KateJean, I can't recommend you anything, while I don't know what does the `joinMetadataAndMetrics()` do.

Comment: sorry about that! My fiddle is here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/KateJean/n2L2fzst/

you can see your added code commented out.

Comment: I think I did solve the problem. I need to do more testing to be sure, but basically  I needed to clear all my entries (by just calling the empty set) before I called by http then my everyFiveMinutes function. As long as I cleared out the old data, I was able to refresh with the new data without keeping the "stale" data on the page as well. 

Thanks for all your help! super appreciated!